# Можно ли и запроса в БД, установить свойства в классе?

Tags: php

У меня такой вопрос.. есть класс и запрос к БД внутри класса,

```
class Customer extends Connection
{
    protected $fname;
    protected $lname;
    protected $email;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->conn=$conn;
    }

    public function get_name()
    {
        return $this->fname;
    }

    public function set_name($fname)
    {
        $this->fname = $fname;
    }


    public function get_info(mysqli $conn) 
    {

        $query = "SELECT customer_id, store_id, first_name, last_name, email,
                         address.address_id AS addressid,
                         address.address AS address,
                         address.district AS district,
                         address.postal_code AS postcode,
                         address.phone AS phone,
                         address.city_id AS cityid 
                  FROM customer
                  INNER JOIN address
                  ON address.address_id  = customer.address_id
                  WHERE customer_id = '1' ";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("ERROR " . mysqli_error($conn)); 

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        { 

          $row->set_name();

        }

    }

}
```

Можно ли из запроса, из массива $row, поочередно установить свойства в этом же классе, что бы потом их передавать или использовать, и если можно то как? Не могу понять, подскажите кто может...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью меджик-метода `__get()`

```
class Customer extends Connection
{
    private $prop;

    public function __get($key){
         if(isset($this->prop[$key])){
            return $this->prop[$key];
         }
        return false;
    } 



public function get_info(mysqli $conn) 
{

... ... ... 

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    { 

      $this->prop = $row;

    }

... ... ... 

}
}
```

Теперь при обращении к `Customer->address_id` вернётся значение `$row['address_id']`, установленное ранее